# Android Nexus S Boot Freeze

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, boot

My Android Nexus S does not boot anymore.
If I start it normally, I get a screen like the following and it won't ever change (tried for hours):

[image: NormalBoot]

I can still go into the boot loader with PowerOff + Volume Up, if I try the RECOVERY option, I just get a screen that looks like this:

[image]

Does anybody know how to install the original google android again, or at least flash it with a similar operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind to end up with Cyanogenmod9 (Ice-Cream-Sandwich):

Here's the full update guide from CyanogenMod's Wiki:
http://oldwiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Nexus_S:_Full_Update_Guide

Here are builds (go for release candidates or stable builds for CM9):
http://get.cm/?device=crespo

Recovery images are here:
http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager/
flash via 'fastboot flash recovery [recovery.img]

Answer (score 0):

To install the stock ICS build: go to https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images and choose your device (mine, for example, a US Nexus S that works with T-Mobile, is https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#sojuimm76d), download the file, then download the surprisingly-not-very-large Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.  Run the sdk manager (it's called "tools/android") which will open a GUI; make sure "Android SDK" and "Android SDK Platform Tools" are checked.  You can clear other check boxes, since those will download very large stuff that you don't need.

Once you've got all that, follow the instructions in the tarball that you first downloaded; roughly, you want to put the sdk's "platform tools" directory on your PATH, power off your phone, then hold the power-up key and power it back on (that'll get it to display the Sekrit Startup Screen); and then on your computer run "fastboot oem unlock" and then "flash-all.sh".

I've done this twice in the last few days (for fun :-) and while it may sound complicated, it's actually pretty easy and worked fine.  (I installed 2.3.6 just for the nostalgia of it and then installed Cyanogenmod and then went back to stock 4.0.4).